# Jquery + css dropdown menu issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of trouble as i do not really use jquery a lot neither do i have a lot of experience with javascript but i found a good working menu that looks pretty good:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    $("#nav > li > a").click(function (e) { 
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100);
            $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected"); 

        } else {
            $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); 
            $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");

            if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); 
                $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);
            }
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); 

    $("body").click(function () { 
        $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); 
        $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
    }); 

});
```

The menu is as simple as this:

```
<li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h3>Submenu #1</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><h3>Submenu #2</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><h3>Submenu #3</h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link 10</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

What i added is a simple login tab that expands and shows you the username and password input but with the current jquery it unselects the parent and it slides back up when i select the input fields.

My question is what do i need to add (or remove) to stop it from sliding up when i press the input fields (and submit button)

Help is much appreciated,
Cheers!

Comment: Am I interpreting the question right: your `form` elements are part of the dropdown? Maybe children of the `li`s?

Comment: Part of it but no not children they replace the links so the whole `<li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>` becomes `<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line :

```
$('#nav').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()})
```

[Tobias Baummeister](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804182/2324107) is right.

You are using `e.stopPropagation()` already but on the first level of navigation. Add it to the entire `ul` and your problem is solved.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Adrdx/

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think your mistake is right here:

```
 $("body").click(function () { 
        $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); 
        $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
    });
```

Since the input-field is also part of your body, it calls this function when it is clicked.

Comment: I checked it and it was the part that stopped it from closing

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the click event of the login form input boxes to stop the event propagating to the body.

```
$('form').on('click', 'input', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Uhm, what i was looking for is to just stop it from sliding back up when someone clicks the input fields but still slide it back up when someone clicks on the body, when i pasted this code above the body function it works but it wont slide anything back up when i click the body and when i paste it below the body function it doesnt work at all? I really am horrible at jquery.. Cheers for the help though